# Playing DVD Video stored on hard-drive

Tags: software-recommendation, video, software-center, dvd, video-player

I am using Movie Player (under Applications -> Sound and Video) to play dvd-video files that are copied on hard-drive.

But it's not playing properly. I have to give each .VOB file to player to play.

Is there any good software that I can get from Ubuntu Software Center, to play DVD Video files that are stored in a directory.

Player should provide me option to select directory, and it should play then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `vlc` or `smplayer` which is in [medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org) for this.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the directory containing the VIDEO_TS dir in nautilus , you should have a shortcut on the top bar for launching Totem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used VLC in the past to play both dvd ISO files, and the various .vob files from DVD disks.

It can also 'play a directory' as if it was a dvd disk i recall.

Just be careful to not accidentally make all folders open with vlc. I tend to just drag/drop files onto the vlc window.

If your system is set up right you can  click Below to install vlc.

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vlc

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best solution is VLC player. It incorporates almost all codecs which are used today.

Answer (score 0):

VLC does this but... if memory recalls correctly so does Totem (and that is what you have now?) and you just need to open the directory where the VOBs are in. When I am at my machine I will have try to see if I was right.

Reference for vlc: [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1572371)