# Which players are known to be able or not to be able to play DVD saved as a directory on a Toshiba AC100 (ARM)

Tags: dvd, video-player, arm, ac100

The answer to this question should help one to choose the player to run in Ubuntu 12.04 on Toshiba AC100 (ARM) if one wants to play a DVD saved in a directory in the filesystem. The layout of the directory is like this:

```
../Jeeves&Wooster_Rus

    Poster.jpg 403.51 KB (413199)
    Side A(Sez1-2) · 4.03 GB
        VIDEO_TS · 4.03 GB
            VIDEO_TS.BUP 12 KB (12288)
            VIDEO_TS.IFO 12 KB (12288)
            VIDEO_TS.VOB 54 KB (55296)
            VTS_01_0.BUP 300 KB (307200)
            VTS_01_0.IFO 300 KB (307200)
            VTS_01_0.VOB 112 KB (114688)
            VTS_01_1.VOB 953.76 MB (1000097792)
            VTS_01_2.VOB 953.68 MB (1000011776)
            VTS_01_3.VOB 953.68 MB (1000015872)
            VTS_01_4.VOB 953.76 MB (1000099840)
            VTS_01_5.VOB 318.38 MB (333852672)
    Side B(Sez3-4) · 4.35 GB
        VIDEO_TS · 4.35 GB
            VIDEO_TS.BUP 12 KB (12288)
            VIDEO_TS.IFO 12 KB (12288)
            VIDEO_TS.VOB 54 KB (55296)
            VTS_01_0.BUP 320 KB (327680)
            VTS_01_0.IFO 320 KB (327680)
            VTS_01_0.VOB 114 KB (116736)
            VTS_01_1.VOB 953.73 MB (1000058880)
            VTS_01_2.VOB 953.71 MB (1000046592)
            VTS_01_3.VOB 953.74 MB (1000071168)
            VTS_01_4.VOB 953.65 MB (999981056)
            VTS_01_5.VOB 639.83 MB (670914560)
```

The individual files with video do not match the "chapters" (episodes) of the DVD. (I've downloaded it from http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=239156.) Its characteristics are:

Video codec: DivX
Audio codec: DVD-Audio
Video: 768x576, 1.85:1, NTSC, color
Audio: 48000 Hz, 6 channels (5.1 surround), 96 Kbit/sec

The default movie player (`totem`) couldn't do it.

For each other player available for Ubuntu 12.04 on ARM, we need to know whether it can play this kind of video flawlessly.

This information will be useful everytime a user wants to play this kind of video and has to select a player that would be working for sure (not to spend efforts and time to try many players).

Answer (score 1):

- The default player (`totem`) can't do it: after showing the beginning a little bit, it is stuck. Or perhaps it just showed nothing. I couldn't test whther navigating between the chapters worked.
- `vlc` shows nothing at all, has to be killed afterwards (`killall vlc`).
- `gnome-mplayer` couldn't open it as a DVD stored in a directory, hence chapter navigation didn't work.
- `smplayer` has a speical menu option to open a DVD stored in a directory. It played it well (although I didn't do the playback for a long time, so I can't tell for sure whether [the video delay problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/180541/19753) happens for this format), chapter navigation worked.

(As for the comparison between the two interfaces to MPlayer--`gnome-mplayer` and `smplayer` on other videos, `gnome-mplayer` sometimes stopped the playback unexpectedly and hung, weheras `smplayer` did never have this problem. So `smplayer` is anyway preferred by me.)

- `gxine` (an interface to Xine): I didn't test it.

Conclusion: `smplayer` can open a DVD stored in a directory and play it well. ([A similar conclusion](https://askubuntu.com/a/39995/19753) in the general, not ARM/AC100-specific case; but it says that besides `smplayer`, `vlc` also works, which is not the case in for my system on a Toshiba AC100.)

Comment: Are you sure that `vlc` cannot play them? It usually works for me when I open the `VIDEO_TS` folder. If the "chapters" of the DVD don't match, I would try playing just the appropriate `*.VOB` files with vlc.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: `vlc` seems just not work on Toshiba AC100 (ARM architecture) completely: independently of the DVD format issue. Cf. http://askubuntu.com/a/180541/19753 .